# googleCloudStorageR, gcs_save() works but gcs_load() does not

Tags: r, google-cloud-storage

We have already authenticated and now have the following code snippet

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_save(
  iris,
  file = 'bucket-folder/iris.rda',
  bucket = 'our-gcs-bucket'
)
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_load(
  file = 'bucket-folder/iris.rda',
  bucket = 'our-gcs-bucket'
)
```

Here, `gcs_save()` works fine to save the RDA in GCS, but gcs_load() does not work. We receive the error:

````
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle): Failed to open file C:\Users\myname\path-to-file\iris.rda.
Request failed [ERROR]. Retrying in 1 seconds...
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle): Failed to open file C:\Users\myname\path-to-file\iris.rda.
Request failed [ERROR]. Retrying in 1.3 seconds...
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to open file C:\Users\myname\path-to-file\iris.rda.
Error: Request failed before finding status code: Failed to open file C:\Users\myname\path-to-file\iris.rda.```
````

I am confused as to why gcs_load() appears to be attempting to open the file locally, rather than grabbing it from our GCS bucket. Are we using the `gcs_load()` function wrong here? How can we retrieve our saved RDA from GCS?

**Edit:** Also perhaps helpful and worth noting, but `iris.rda` saved in GCS is listed as being saved with Type text/plain per the GCS UI. Shouldn't the type here be something like RDA or RData, rather than text/plain?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry missed this at the time.  Its due to you saving the object with a folder name that GCS just regards as a / in the filename, then when you download it again it tries to put it in that folder structure but the folder does not exist.

To fix you could create the folder locally with `dir.create()`:

```r
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_save(
  iris,
  file = 'bucket-folder/iris.rda',
  bucket = 'our-gcs-bucket'
)
dir.create("bucket-folder")
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_load(
  file = 'bucket-folder/iris.rda',
  bucket = 'our-gcs-bucket'
)
✓ Saved bucket-folder/iris.rda to bucket-folder/iris.rda  ( 1.1 Kb )
[1] TRUE
```

Or you could specify the file location to be in an existing folder location (e.g. without the folder name) with the argument `saveToDisk`:

```r
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_load(
  file = 'bucket-folder/iris.rda',
  saveToDisk = "iris.rda",
  bucket = 'our-gcs-bucket'
)
✓ Saved bucket-folder/iris.rda to iris.rda  ( 1.1 Kb )
[1] TRUE
```